# Seqeulize Error: Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'

Tags: sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize with ExpressJS and I have an `Organization` model which is as follows:

```
const Organization = db.define("organization", {
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING(50),
    allowNull: false,
  },
});
module.exports = Organization;
```

This name in this `Organization` model is a foreign key in the User model as `organization` ( The idea is that many users can join an organization - or Many users can join in an organization but an user always belongs to one organization)
The User Model looks like this:

```
const User = db.define("user", {
  first_name: {
    type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING(50),
    allowNull: false,
  },
organization: {
    type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING(25),
    allowNull: false,
  } 
});
User.belongsTo(Organization, {
  foreignKey: "organization",
  as: "organizationName",
});
```

However, I am unable to create a new organization first by:

```
const { name } = req.body;
  try {
    const organization = await Organization.create({
      name,
    });
    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      created: organization,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    next(new ErrorResponse(`Error! ${error.message}`, 400));
  }
```

It throws me this error: `ErrorResponse: Error! Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'`.
However I am able to create a new user with an organization name, and it automatically creates an organization in the organization table.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding an id column to the table.

Comment: Please stick with answer, don't post counter question.